# How can I debug an issue I have with a teams bot?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, bots, microsoft-teams

I have build a sample bot from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-dotnet-app-studio and published it as described in the page using ngrok. I can access the app with its public ngrok address.

When I try to add the app for our team using App Studio I get a general error

```
Something went wrong, please try again later.
```

On fiddler I see "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request" when teams sends the request to api/mt/emea/beta/teams/..../@thread.skype/apps/definitions

Is there any chance I can debug that further?

[image]

Comment: Could you please check if [sideloading is enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/MicrosoftTeams/enable-features-office-365#external-apps) by your tenant admin?

Comment: The missing sideloading enabled setting has a correct errormessage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your link is simply **not found, make sure that your link exists**, Microsoft tends to use 400 instead of 404, this can be seen here https://teams.microsoft.com/should-be-404, the error that you are getting is simply because it cannot find the `@thread.skype`, thanks to Microsoft for good use of error message! *#SomethingWentWrong*, fix your link and your bot should work just fine!